# I am getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while running JUNIT tests in Struts application

Tags: java

```
Error in console for all test cases i am running in STRUTS maven project:
testOverride(com.cisco.mcm.testcase.TestOverrides)  Time elapsed: 3.969 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.cisco.servicesales.mcm.utils.MCMDataUtil.getDataSource(MCMDataUtil.java:55)
    at com.cisco.servicesales.mcm.utils.MCMDataUtil.getServices(MCMDataUtil.java:45)
    at com.cisco.mcm.dao.AccessManagementDAO.getUserData(AccessManagementDAO.java:83)


MCMDataUtil.java(line 55 ): 
public static DataSource getDataSource(String ConnectionPoolName) {

        System.out.println("Inside getDatasource...1");
        logger.info("Inside getDataSource Method");
        DataSource dataSource = null;   
        System.out.println(":Inside getDatasource...2");

line 55:        ApplicationContext context = SpringSingleton.getContext();
        System.out.println(":Inside getDatasource...3");
```

Due to this error bean is not getting instantiated:

```
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:334)
at 
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:980)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [dataSource-beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource com.cisco.mcm.util.WASConnectionPoolManager.loadPool(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OracleWallet
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.Ab
```

Can you please help to get rid of this error?
I am trying since long time and unable to find any solution.

Comment: ApplicationContext context = SpringSingleton.getContext();  is the main issue

Answer (score 0):

If you read your way through the exception, sometimes it will tell you about nested exceptions. These can be hard to read if you aren't used to the stack traces. In this case, your root cause is:

> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OracleWallet

That tells us the JVM can't find `oracle.security.pki.OracleWallet` to load, in order to create a connection to the database. Do you have `oracle.security.pki.OracleWallet` on your classpath as part of another jar?

Comment: For this which jar  i should have ?Currently i have ojdbc14 jar in my project .